# Making a game in win forms, trying to use key down events

Tags: c#, winforms

I've tried to implement key down event catching in WinForms but the data doesn't seem to be going to the method. I've also got some buttons on the form, and it's cycling between them when pressing the arrow keys (These are the keys that I'm trying to get the key down data from).

What I tried doing was going to each button (one button for each key) and generating a method for the key down method.

Comment: Code? Where's your code? Nowadays you are better off making a game in Unity3D. Still C# but a fraction of the work required to get results.

Comment: I'm guessing that you need `KeyPreview = true;` inside your `Form` constructor. Am i right?

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: From the KeyDown docs: _"Certain keys, such as the TAB, RETURN, ESC, and **arrow keys** are handled by controls automatically. To have these keys raise the KeyDown event, you must override the IsInputKey method in each control on your form. The code for the override of the IsInputKey would need to determine if one of the special keys is pressed and return a value of true. Instead of overriding the IsInputKey method, you can handle the PreviewKeyDown event and set the IsInputKeyproperty to true. For a code example, see the PreviewKeyDown event."_

Comment: Link to the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that I think may help you. Instead of using buttons you could just override the form's ProcessCmdKey (Which, when called will reference what key was pressed on the form).

Just make sure that PreviewKey is set to true, so that any events caught by any controls are passed down to the form.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
    //Move in the right direction relative to the key pressed
    switch (keyData) {
        case Keys.Up:
            //Do stuff
            break;

        case Keys.Down:
            //Do stuff
            break;

        case Keys.Left:
            //Do stuff
            break;

        case Keys.Right:
            //Do stuff
            break;
    }

    //Call the base class' ProcessCmdKey method.
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```